Showing that the set of a sequence going to $+\infty$ has a minimum
Link to question
The Question: Let $a_n$ be a sequence of real numbers s.t $a_n \rightarrow+\infty$ as $n \rightarrow +\infty$, and let $A$ be the set of all its terms, i.e, $A=\{a_n\}$. Prove that $A$ has a minimum.

The sequence $1,0,2,1,3,2,....,n,n-1,...$ goes to $+\infty$ but is not increasing.

It's not that the sequence is eventually increasing.  It's that eventually all the terms are a higher than a determined value and the there are only a finite number of terms that are not.

Hint: Since $a_n \to \infty$, there exists some $N>1$ such that $a_n > a_1$ for all $n > N$.

Please use latex to format your question.

Also you can't take derivative of sequences.   I'm afraid.... you don't have it.  Here's two hints.  1) Every finite set has a minimum.  2) If $a_n \to \infty$ then for all $M$ there is an $n$ so that for all $k>n$ we have $a_k > M$.  3)  The set ${a_1,a_2,......, a_n}$ is a finite set

"Is this in the right direction at all? "  I'm afraid it's not.  "Or would I need to apply something like MVT, IVT, etc.."  A sequence is a function on integers which are discrete separated points that have no connected intervals at all.  MVT, IVT, derivatives and anything to do with calculus only make sense over connected intervals.  I'm afraid you can't use any of those.

No MVT, no IVT, just apply the definition of $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = +\infty$.

This shouldn’t be getting downvoted. It is a genuine question where the attempt is shown.

Let $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^+}$ be a sequence of real numbers such that for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists some $N \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $a_n > x$ for all $n > N$ (this is what is meant by $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \infty$).
Consider $a_1 \in \mathbb{R}$. By what we just said, there exists some $N \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $a_n > a_1$ for all $n > N$. Consider then the finite set of real numbers $\{a_1, \dots, a_N \}$. By induction, you know that any finite set of real numbers has a smallest element (minimum); for this case, suppose that minimum is $a_K$ ($K \in \mathbb{Z}^+$). Then since $a_K \le a_n$ for each $n \in \{1, \dots, N \}$, and $a_1 < a_n \implies a_K < a_n$ for each $n > N$, then $a_K$ is the smallest element of the set $\{ a_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^+}$, as desired.

Your statement "By $a_n \rightarrow +\infty$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, we know that large enough $n > N > 0$, $a_n$ is increasing." is a wrong statement. Consider the sequence $$a_n= \left\{
  \begin{array}{ll} 
      n, & \mbox{if  $n$ even,} \\
      n+2, & \mbox{if $n$ is odd.} 
      \end{array}
\right.$$
Observe that $a_n \rightarrow +\infty$, but for any big $n>N>0$, $a_n$ is not an increasing sequence. Proof of the statement is given below.
As the sequence $a_n \rightarrow \infty$, by the definition for any $M \in \mathbb{R}$, there is $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a_n > M$ for all $n > N$. Take $M >a_1$, then the set $B := \{a_1, a_2, \dots, a_N\}$ is a finite nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}$, hence a compact set. Since a compact set attains minimum, we have $\alpha \in B$, such that $\alpha \leq x$ for all $x \in B$. Observe that since $a_1 < M$, we have $\alpha < M$. Hence $\alpha < M < a_n$, for all $n > N$. This implies $\alpha \leq a_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Since $\alpha \in B \subset A$, we have $\alpha$ is the minimum of $A$.
